# Do red5 always work same way on windows and linux?

Tags: java, windows, linux, red5, netstream

i have developed a simple application that record a video from webcam using flex and red5.
This application is been made using flex and extending red5 Application adapter, on client side i use NetStream.publish() method, and on server side i will find into stream folder my recorded flv files, i have tried it on windows host and linux server.
In my application i am splitting video by audio using 2 different netstreams while i record there are an audio.flv.ser and a video.flv.ser files and the final flv files get created from .ser files.

The difference i noticed between windows host and linux server, running centos6, excecution are these ones:

1. On windows host the 2 flv files get processed together, i can see that their size change every moment 'ntil it reachs .ser files size, but on linux size every flv file is processed one by one, first video.flv is processed once its done audio.flv start getting processed.
2. Windows host is a lot faster, abt 10 times faster, than linux server, but linux server is running on a less powerful cpu than linux server (T4400 server vs. Xeon quad core).

Why is there a so big difference in the way red5 runs on windows and linux?Red5 is written in java,the algorithm workflow should be the same either in windows and linux systems,shouldn't it?

Comment: maybe the quad-core CPU means that the Windows server can do more work at the same time.

Comment: The try has been made on 2 different machines, the windows host is a notebook running windows7 with t4400 pentium cpu, and the linux centos6 is running on xeon quad core processor, the paradox is that a notebook is having a better performance than a xeon server.